# Is it possible to cancel a child promise when parent is cancelled?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, cancellation

I have this code (using Bluebird Promise):

```
const promise = loadSomething(id)
  .then(something => {
    loadParentOfSomething(something.parentId);
    return something;
  });
```

When I then do `promise.cancel()` the `getSomething` is cancelled, but the `getSomethingParent` is not.

Is there a way to, when `getSomething` promise is cancelled, I can also get the `getSomethingParent` promise to cancel?

Both load functions returns a cancellable async promise with an HTTP request, and the reason I want to cancel them is because they can sometimes take a while to load and when for example a user navigates away (SPA) the response is no longer needed.

Comment: Is `getSomethingParent()` an asynchronous task that can be cancelled at all? It looks pretty much like a synchronous function now - and you're not doing anything with its result.

Comment: Yes, it also returns a cancellable promise. Sorry, should've made that clearer.

Comment: But you are not doing anything with that promise (but throwing it away)? Don't you get a Bluebird warning [about that](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it)?

Comment: Not that I've seen. It's a promise that eventually fires off a loaded event via a store though so it is doing something. Just not right there.

Comment: …and because of that, `promise` doesn't know about it and has no incentive to cancel it.

Comment: Exactly, so I'm looking for a way to make promise somehow know about it so it can pull it down with it.

Comment: See my answer on how to do that. Or does that not do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are actually looking for

```
const promise1 = loadSomething(id);
const promise2 = promise1.then(something => { return loadParentOfSomething(something.parentId); });
//                                            ^^^^^^
promise2.catch(e => void "ignore"); // prevent unhandled rejections
```

Then you can keep using `promise1` to access the result, but also call `promise2.cancel()`. This cancellation will be possible even after `promise1` settled.

Comment: Actually tried doing that, but didn't seem to make any difference, so might be something else going on here. 

Comment: …or maybe I don't understand how Bluebird cancellation actually works. Let's wait for Benjamin Gruenbaum to come around and confirm.

Comment: Managed to work "around" it by just not doing that parent loading as it turned out that parent data actually came back as part of `something.parent`. Thought it was just a small snippet, but after looking at it a bit more, it was actually pretty much the same data as came back from `loadParentOfSomething`. But yeah, would be great if someone could shed some light on this cancellation, because I really think it *should've* worked the way it was. 

Answer (score -1):

Define a function as the second parameter of the `then` callback. Example:

```
const promise = getSomething(id)
  .then(something => {
    getSomethingParent(something.parentId);
    return something;
  }, error => {
    console.error(error)
  });
```

When you call `promise.reject()` then `getSomethingParent` will not be called.
[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: `getSomethingParent` has already been called though. So the `getSomething` promise has already been fulfilled, but `getSomethingParent` has not. I'd like `getSomethingParent` to be cancelled when `cancel` is called, regardless of status of `getSomething`. If that makes sense. 

Comment: No it hasn't, it will only get called when `getSomething` is done. That's why it is placed in the `then`.

Comment: If the `getSomething` promise has been fulfilled then how are you cancelling it?

Comment: Whether errors are caught has absolutely nothing do with `getSomethingParent` or even cancellation in general.

Comment: @Bergi by default if an error function is not defined, the `then` callback is called in both success and error cases. So if the user wants to handle cases wherein the promise is `rejected` then defining a error function will help. Here is a [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: @varunagarwal Uh, no. You must have horribly misunderstood that documentation. What sentence do you refer to specifically, maybe I can fix the wiki to clear this up?

Comment: Oops my bad. Sorry about that.

Answer (score -2):

If you prepare a dummy promise to reference `loadSomethingOfParent` you should be able to cancel it within `loadSomething`.

```
// Create a dummy promise to reference `loadParentOfSomething`
var dummyPromise = Promise.resolve(); 

// Pass `dummyPromise` to `loadSomething`
const promise = loadSomething(id, dummyPromise).then(something => {
  dummyPromise = loadParentOfSomething(something.parentId);
  return something;
});
```

`loadSomething` will need an `onCancel` handler which will execute when the promise is cancelled.

```
function loadSomething(id, promise) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject, onCancel) {
    // Do your stuff

    // The `.cancel()` handler
    onCancel(function() {
      promise.cancel();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: This does not work - `promise` inside `loadSomething` will always refer to the `Promise.resolve()` dummy promise, not its replacement. JS doesn't have pass-by-reference. Also I doubt that the `onCancel` callback will be run after the `loadSomething()` promise called `resolve`/`reject`.